# DataGrid repeats the data retrieved from database in a single row twice

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working on a point of sale project in WPF and i want to retrieve all the records (associated with the current or last customer id) in to datagrid. I have done the same work in other project while selecting the * from a table and retrieving it. But this time don't know why this code doesn't work.i am including the output image with my question kindly have a look at that too.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="376" Width="864">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1C75BC" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BarCode" Binding="{Binding BarCode}" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductName" Binding="{Binding ProductName}"  Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="UnitPrice" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SalePrice" Binding="{Binding SalePrice}" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Width="*" />                       
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
private void FillDataGrid(int counttt)
{
    SqlConnection connn = db.getConnection();
    connn.Open();
    string CmdString = string.Empty;
    //DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
    //String d = (dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    CmdString = "SELECT BarCode, ProductName, UnitPrice, SalePrice, Quantity From CustomerSale WHERE CId = '" + counttt + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, connn);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("CustomerSale");
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    connn.Close();
}
```

[image: here is the output image when the code was executed last time]

Comment: does your datatable is populating with data?

Comment: yes... but the data repeats twice every time as shown in the output image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable `DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns`. You created columns for each data property in markup (`<DataGrid.Columns>`) and when ItemsSource is set, DataGrid also generates columns for every property because default value for AutoGenerateColumns is `true`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" ...
```