# Data shows twice in DataGrid

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio-2015, datagrid

I created DataGrid like this in XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgSalons" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="572" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ИД" Binding="{Binding Path = id}" Width="*"/> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Назив" Binding="{Binding Path = name}"  Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Адреса" Binding="{Binding Path = adress}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Телефон" Binding="{Binding Path = email}"  Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Интернет адреса" Binding="{Binding Path = web_site}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ПИБ" Binding="{Binding Path = tin}"  Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Матични Број" Binding="{Binding Path = uid}"  Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Жиро рачун" Binding="{Binding Path = bank_account}"  Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

And I tryed to fill it with datas from mySql by click on Button "Show" (Прикажи):

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                    string connection = "server=localhost;user id=root; password=root; database=pop-sf40-database";
                    string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM salons");

                MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
                cn.Open();

                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(data);
                dgSalons.DataContext = data;
    }
```

Before clicking on button it looks like this:
[image]

And after [image]

How to fill cells only once by binding?

Comment: Set AutoGenerateColumns="False" in the DataGrid element, if your problem is that you are seeing two of each column. If the problem is that the rows are showing twice, that's different.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's it. Solved. Thanks. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGrid repeats the data retrieved from database in a single row twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993716/datagrid-repeats-the-data-retrieved-from-database-in-a-single-row-twice)